# How can I improve the style of this table in latex?

Tags: tables, packages, tabularx, multirow, multicolumn

I would like to center all the elements of the table and improve the style of this one.

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|l|r|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{text} & \multicolumn{3}{r|}{Aproach}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                \\ \hline
another text                              & other one                                                                                                                                                            & another one                                                                                                                                                         & other                                                                                                                                                     \\ \hline
something                  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}r@{}}another fancy text:\\ another text:\\ another text:\\ another one text:\\ another one text:\\ another text:\\ some text:\\ F-Beta another text:\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Exactitud:\\ another text:\\ another text:\\ another one text:\\ another one text:\\ another text:\\ some text:\\ another one textta another text:\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Exactitud:\\ another text:\\ another text:\\ another one text:\\ another one text:\\ another text:\\ some text:\\ F-Beta another text:\end{tabular} \\ \hline
                                     & 0.01                                                                                                                                                           &                                                                                                                                                                &                                                                                                                                                                \\ \hline
Gnu                                  & 92.50                                                                                                                                                          &                                                                                                                                                                &                                                                                                                                                                \\ \hline
Emu                                  & 33.33                                                                                                                                                          &                                                                                                                                                                &                                                                                                                                                                \\ \hline
Armadillo                            & 8.99                                                                                                                                                           &                                                                                                                                                                &                                                                                                                                                                \\ \hline
Total:                               & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                                                                                          &                                                                                                                                                                &                                                                                                                                                                \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

How can I make the above table look as the below?

[image]

Comment: I would like to pimp this aproach any suggestion?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand{\cenMultlCell}[2][c]{\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \footnotesize\centering % needed, as table is to wide
    \begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=2.2]SS} % supposing that you want to put numbers in the emty cells
        \toprule
        text & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Aproach} \\\cmidrule(l){2-4}
        another text & {other one} & {another one} & {other} \\\midrule
        something 
        & {\cenMultlCell{another fancy text:\\ another text:\\ another text:\\ another one text:\\ another one text:\\ another text:\\ some text:\\ F-Beta another text:}} 
        & {\cenMultlCell{Exactitud:\\ another text:\\ another text:\\ another one text:\\ another one text:\\ another text:\\ some text:\\ another one text:}}
        & {\cenMultlCell{Exactitud:\\ another text:\\ another text:\\ another one text:\\ another one text:\\ another text:\\ some text:\\ F-Beta another text:}} \\\midrule
        & 0.01 & & \\
        Gnu & 92.50 & & \\
        Emu & 33.33 & & \\
        Armadillo & 8.99 & & \\\midrule\midrule
        Total: & & & \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{your caption}\label{tab:label}
\end{table}

A reference to \autoref{tab:label}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I didnt understood how to aproach this.

Comment: I tried the following: `\\\midrule
         \tabitem text1\\
         \tabitem text2\
        & {\cenMultlCell{another fancy text:\\ another text:\\ another text:\\ another one text:\\ another one text:\\ another text:\\ some text:\\ F-Beta another text:}}
\\\midrule` with this setup: `\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}`. The problem is that I am having space issues. Any idea of how to preserve the spaces for each colummn?.

Answer (score 2):

I have the following suggestions:

- To center the elements of a column in a `tabular` environment, use the `c` column type instead of `l` or `r`.
- To center a `tabular` environment inside a `table` environment, use the `\centering` instruction.
- You have several `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{...}` "wrapper" statements. They don't exactly hurt, but they don't seem to be necessary either. I would omit them.
- The `[c]` positioning specifier is the default for `tabular` environments. Reduce clutter by not specifying it.
- You seem to provide a lot of space characters to format the tabular material visually. I'd use more linebreak characters in the input to make the input material more easily parsable to human eyes.

.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % choose page margins appropriately
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
text & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Approach}
\\ \hline
another text & other one & another one & other 
\\ \hline
something & 
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
   another fancy text:\\ 
   another text:\\ 
   another text:\\ 
   another one text:\\ 
   another one text:\\ 
   another text:\\ 
   some text:\\ 
   F-Beta another text:
\end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
   Exactitud:\\ 
   another text:\\ 
   another text:\\ 
   another one text:\\ 
   another one text:\\ 
   another text:\\ 
   some text:\\ 
   another one textta another text:
\end{tabular} & 
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
   Exactitud:\\ 
   another text:\\ 
   another text:\\ 
   another one text:\\ 
   another one text:\\ 
   another text:\\ 
   some text:\\ 
   F-Beta another text:
\end{tabular}
\\ \hline
          &  0.01 & & \\ \hline
Gnu       & 92.50 & & \\ \hline
Emu       & 33.33 & & \\ \hline
Armadillo &  8.99 & & \\ \hline
Total:    & & & 
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the r's and l's with c's in the tabular definitions.  And a bit of code reorganization will make it easier to edit.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{text} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Aproach}\\ \hline
another text  & other one & another one      & other     \\ \hline
something     & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
                another fancy text:\\ 
                another text:\\ 
                another text:\\ 
                another one text:\\ 
                another one text:\\ 
                another text:\\ 
                some text:\\
                F-Beta another text:
                \end{tabular}        
              & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
                    Exactitud:\\ 
                    another text:\\ 
                    another text:\\ 
                    another one text:\\ 
                    another one text:\\ 
                    another text:\\ 
                    some text:\\ 
                    another one textta another text:
                \end{tabular}              
               & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
                    Exactitud:\\ 
                    another text:\\ 
                    another text:\\ 
                    another one text:\\ 
                    another one text:\\ 
                    another text:\\ 
                    some text:\\ 
                    F-Beta another text:
                    \end{tabular} \\ \hline
       & 0.01   &    &            \\ \hline
Gnu    & 92.50  &    &                   \\ \hline
Emu    & 33.33  &    &     \\ \hline
Armadillo       & 8.99    &      &     \\ \hline
Total:   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}      &  &   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, I got this warning: `LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type H <return> for immediate help. ... l.29 \begin{document} Your command was ignored. Type I <command> <return> to replace it with another command, or <return> to continue without it.` I tried: [H!] and still the same, any idea of how to solve this issue?.

Comment: @ml_guy It compiles ok on my system (Win 8.1, MikTex, Texmaker).  Try the revised code which I neatened.